# How do I get Google Cloud Function to create a Machine Image?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I am writing a cloud function that will run off a weekly cron on google cloud scheduler that will create a machine image of a Jenkins Controller as a backup. I wrote the Cloud Function and the code completes with a 200 but nothing happens. What do I need to change in order to get this to work?

```
import requests
from datetime import date
import json
import functions_framework


@functions_framework.http
def create_backup(request):
    try: 
        today = date.today()
        r = requests.post('https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project-1/global/machineImages', data={'name': f"jenkins-backup-{today}","sourceInstance": 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project-1/global/instances/jenkins'})
        return 'OK'
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return "ERROR", 400
```

Comment: 1) Your code is not using authorization. 2) Your code is not checking the response which probably reports an error. 3) I do not think the source instance string is correct - specify the zone instead of global.

Comment: Why a function to create an image? A CI/CD pipeline (Cloud Build) shouldn't be more suit to that?

Comment: As per the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images/create-machine-images) you can use gcloud command 

`gcloud compute machine-images create MACHINE_IMAGE_NAME \
    --source-instance=SOURCE_VM_NAME`
to create machine image from the running instance.If you are looking for scheduled creation you can create a cron job schedule to create a machine image for above.